# paypal rest api execute error

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, paypal

I'm trying to implement a PayPal payment in a Wordpress theme .
I get the token, create the payment, redirect the user to approval link , get the aproval from  user but for some reason i cannot execute the payment" the curl response is empty.

Here is the code (i double checked the execute url and token and they are correct)

```
if (isset($_GET['token']) && isset($_GET['PayerID']) ){
   $received_token     =   sanitize_text_field ( $_GET['token'] );
   $received_payerId   =   sanitize_text_field ( $_GET['PayerID'] );
   $execute_urls       =   get_option('paypal_processing');
   $payment_execute_url=   $execute_urls[$current_user->ID];
   $execute_urls[$current_user->ID]    =   '';
   update_option('paypal_processing',$execute_urls);

   $payment_execute = array(
    'payer_id' => $received_payerId
       );
   $json = json_encode($payment_execute);

   $json_resp = make_post_call($payment_execute_url, $json,$received_token);
   print_r($json_resp);
   echo "Payment Execute processed " . $json_resp['id'] ." with state '".    $json_resp['state']."'";
   }





 function make_post_call($url, $postdata,$token) {
    $curl = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$token,
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            ));

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
    #curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    $response = curl_exec( $curl );
    if (empty($response)) {
       // some kind of an error happened
           print 'curl error';
       curl_close($curl); // close cURL handler
     } else {
     $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        //  echo "Time took: " . $info['total_time']*1000 . "ms\n";
    curl_close($curl); // close cURL handler
    if($info['http_code'] != 200 && $info['http_code'] != 201 ) {
        //echo "Received error: " . $info['http_code']. "\n";
        //echo "Raw response:".$response."\n";
        exit('paypal error');
     }
  }

     // Convert the result from JSON format to a PHP array 
    $jsonResponse = json_decode($response, TRUE);
    return $jsonResponse;
     }
```

Comment: Please check  this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651716/paypal-rest-api-for-payments-returns-null-in-the-sandbox  Its similar to the question which u have asked.

Comment: What info does the curl verbose switch give you? Any response headers? Can you post the execution url?

Comment: @lib 4 - that situation inolves missing headers - which i have set. Thx for the answer

Comment: @adyv no response from curl , this is the execution url  https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-0W18059016964772RKIU5RBA/execute

Answer (score 2):

when you return from the approval url, the previously stored information of the token and the execute url is lost. it becomes empty. You need to either store it in a cookie or database table and retrieve it when you return to your site to execute